# No puedo realizar una consulta a la API por el buscador hasta refrescar la página

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una página simple para practicar que me permita implementar un buscador, para esto estoy usando la API de themovieDb, pero al momento de querer realizar una busqueda, no se actualizan los resultados, solo la primera vez que lo hago, pero hasta no apretar F5 y refrescar la página, no me trae los resultados, como recién comienzo en react no sé muy bien que puede estar pasando.

Dejo el código del componente del buscador:

```
import React from 'react';
import swAlert from '@sweetalert/with-react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Search = () => {

const navigate = useNavigate();

const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const keyword = e.currentTarget.keyword.value.trim();

    if(keyword.length === 0){
        swAlert(<h2>Tiene que escribir una palabra clave</h2>)
    } else if (keyword.length < 4){
      swAlert(<h2>Por favor, escribe más de 4 caracteres</h2>)
    } else {
          e.currentTarget.keyword.value = "";
          navigate(`/resultados?keyword=${keyword}`);
    }
 }


return (
<form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
<label className='form-label'>
<input className='form-control' type="text" name='keyword' placeholder='Buscar..' />
</label>
<button className='mx-2' type='submit'>Buscar</button>
</form>
 )
}

export default Search;
```

Y dejo el código del componente de resultados, que es en donde tengo problemas para volver a buscar y que me traiga los resultados.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import swAlert from "@sweetalert/with-react";

const Results = () => {

 let query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let keyword = query.get("keyword");

const [moviesResults, setMoviesResults] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 const endPoint = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie? 
api_key=76470263ef8b82c9b2248e7c930682fd&language=en-US&query=${keyword}`;

axios
  .get(endPoint)
  .then((response) => {
    const moviesArray = response.data.results;
    if (moviesArray.length === 0) {
      swAlert(<h2>No hubo resultados</h2>);
    }
    setMoviesResults(moviesArray);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    });
}, [keyword]);

return (
<>
  <h1>Buscaste: {keyword}</h1>
  {moviesResults.length === 0 && <h3>No hay resultados</h3>}

  <div className="row">
    {moviesResults.map((oneMovie) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-4" key={oneMovie.id}>
          <div className="card">
            <img
              src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${oneMovie.poster_path}`}
              className="card-img-top"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{oneMovie.title}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">
                {oneMovie.overview.substring(0, 70)}
              </p>
              <Link
                to={`/detalle?movieID=${oneMovie.id}`}
                className="btn btn-primary">
                View detail
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Results;
```

Se supone que debería dejarme hacer una búsqueda al apretar el botón de buscar, pero nada ocurre, ni errores por consola ni nada, simplemente se cambia la ruta en la barra de direcciones, pero no me actualiza la página, espero puedan iluminarme,gracias!

Comment: estas usando el `react-router-dom` para hacer el navigate, también puedes usarlo para obtener los valores que cambian en la url, y con eso debería funcionar, te dejo un link con un ejemplo funcionando. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-query-parameters-kp309y?from-embed=&file=/example.js:727-738

Comment: Hola! gracias, pero recién comienzo a usar react y no estoy entendiendo bien como debería hacerlo con react-router-dom para obtener los valores, gracias.

Comment: puedes hacerlo con este hook `const { search } = useLocation();`  y luego usas el `query.get("keyword")` en el useEffect